# Unable to run user service. Exception: Failed to start Java, ServiceStart returned 4

Tags: java, windows, service, windows-services

I have created a service using tutorial http://web.archive.org/web/20090228071059/http://blog.platinumsolutions.com/node/234

I have created files as below:

```
C:\MyService1

\bin
    \myService1.exe
    \myService1w.exe
\classes
    \com\services\MyService1.class
    \HelloWorld.jar
\logs
```

Now when I execute myService1.exe, service is not getting started.
I am getting below message in my log

```
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [info]  [ 3968] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [info]  [ 3968] Running 'MyService1' Service...
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [info]  [ 4204] Starting service...
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [error] [ 5372] FindClass com/services/MyService1 failed
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [error] [ 4204] Failed to start Java
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [error] [ 4204] ServiceStart returned 4
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [info]  [ 3968] Run service finished.
[2015-06-02 15:23:29] [info]  [ 3968] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

In my stderror file, below is reported:

```
2015-06-02 15:23:29 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/services/MyService1 (wrong name: services/MyService1)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I have my environment variables as below:

```
 CLASSPATH: .;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;
 JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0;
 Path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

When I check Event Viewer, I get:

> The MyService1 service terminated with service-specific error The system cannot open the file.

I searched a lot for what a service program should actually contain but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made bellow changes to make my service work successfully.

Folder Structure:

```
C:\MyService1
    \myService1.exe
    \myService1w.exe
    \MyService1.class
    \HelloWorld.jar
    \logs
```

Java Class (Daemon Class):

- Created java class in default package
- The class has two static methods: start() and stop()
- start() should have a infinite loop

Below is the snippet from my class.

```
static boolean isRunning = true;
static boolean isJobsRunning = false;

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static void start(String []args) {
    String command = "run.bat";
    System.out.println("Started JobServices successfully");
    while(isRunning){
        if(!isJobsRunning) { //the job should run only once after the service is started
            try {
                System.out.println("Running batch file");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                isJobsRunning = true;
                System.out.println("Executed batch file successfully");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to execute Jobs jar");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Completed JobService");

}

public static void stop(String args[]) {
     if(!isRunning) 
         return;

     isRunning = false;
     System.out.println("JobService Stopped successfully");
}
```

Link that helped me to get my service in running state: http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/may/01/transforming-java-programs-into-windows-services-u/

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced the same problem when running spring boot application as a service using procrun.
My mistake was i gave path of my main class as the startup class. This got resolved when i used `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` as the startup class. the class that you should use as the startup class can be found in the 
MANIFEST.MF inside the jar